# Python write file Wrong Strings

Tags: python, file, utf-8

I am trying to read an xml file, replace some text, then write over the file.

input file:

```
<text>A&Z</text>
```

source:

```
with open(file, 'rb') as f:
    newText=f.read().decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
    newText= newText.replace("&","and")
with open(relative_file_path+'/'+fileP, "wb") as f:
    print('nt',newText)
    f.write(newText.encode('utf-8'))
```

print nt:

```
nt <�t�e�x�t�>�A�and�Z�<�/�t�e�x�t�>�
```

when printing nt there is a null � character between every character except the and.

[image]

output file:

```
<text>A湡dZ</text>
```

I use decode('utf-8','ignore') because there is an invalid start character in my xml and required to read the file.

---

## Solved

thanks for everyone's help.

```
def stripped(stripstring):
    mpa = dict.fromkeys(range(32))
    stripstring =  stripstring.translate(mpa)
    return stripstring

with open(relative_file_path+'/'+fileP, mode='rb') as f:
    newText=f.read().decode('utf-8-sig', 'ignore')
    newText = stripped(newText)
    newText= newText.replace("&","and")
         
with open(relative_file_path+'/'+fileP, "w") as f:
    f.write(newText)
```

Comment: Remove the invalid character first...

Comment: why read binary - read text? google UFT8-bom and see if thats your "invalid start character".

Comment: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

if i remove 'rb'

Comment: Have you tried decoding with UTF-16?